# XNA & Lidgren 3d networking game not drawing other models/players

Tags: 3d, xna, lidgren

I'm using the xna game engine and Lidgren library for networking. I have tested and made a 2d game where the clients connect to the server and the clients can see other players. However I've moved to trying to create a 3D game and the clients connect to the server and pass the X,Y, and Z coordinates. So I have the Position's of each model but I can't seem to get the clients to draw the other players/models. What am I missing? I'm assuming it is with my draw logic but I am just stumped. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I have a game class and a model class. The game class has the basic logic for an xna game with a heightmap, and the model class is where the model logic is housed.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you can show us? We cant just guess.

Comment: I had a very similar problem to this, and I had to rewrite my client code to sort it out.  Post some code so the good people of SO can help.

Comment: Ok you can download a zip of the sourcecode here. [Download Code](http://mitchellconsultants.org/code/) There was too much code I needed to show for it to make sense to anyone. Like I said the client/server is working fine. But I'm having problems displaying the other models/players on the screen. I know I may need to rewrite a lot of the code for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Changed up the client to load, reposition, and draw other models. :)